# beautifulsoup4: how to parse a forum post?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, pycharm

I have multiple occurences of the following (simplified) data structure as found in a forum software:

```html
<li id="post12345" class="anchorFixedHeader" style="order: 1">
  <div class="messagesidebar member" item-prop="author">
    <div class="messageauthor">
      <div class="messageauthorcontainer">
        <a id="mac12">
          <span class="username" itemprop="text">MostInnovativeUsernameEver</span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="messagecontent">
    <div class="messagebody">
      <div class="messagetext" itemprop="text">
        Text before the quote.
        <blockquote class="quotebox">
          <div class="quoteboxcontent">
            <p>
              Hello, I'm a quote.
            </p>
          </div>
        </blockquote>
        Text after the class.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

What I want to do for each occurence is to extract the username and for each username the corresponding messagecontent. I could do that succesfully, if there wasn't a single problem: the quote. When I print the extracted data in the console the data structure of the quote (naturally) gets messed up.

What I (seem) to need is the text before the quote, the quote itself and the text after the quote to deal with them separetely. I tried a bunch of stuff but don't quite find my way around in beautifulsoup just yet.

Ugh ... do you guys understand what I try to do?

Comment: Please, provide an example of the result you want to achieve and what you actually achieve. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if I understood your question, here is a way to solve:

```py
import re

import bs4

html = """<li id="post12345" class="anchorFixedHeader" style="order: 1">
  <div class="messagesidebar member" item-prop="author">
    <div class="messageauthor">
      <div class="messageauthorcontainer">
        <a id="mac12">
          <span class="username" itemprop="text">MostInnovativeUsernameEver</span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="messagecontent">
    <div class="messagebody">
      <div class="messagetext" itemprop="text">
        Text before the quote.
        <blockquote class="quotebox">
          <div class="quoteboxcontent">
            <p>
              Hello, I'm a quote.
            </p>
          </div>
        </blockquote>
        Text after the class.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>"""

forum_posts = []
re_break_line = re.compile(r'[^\n].*')

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, features='html.parser')
posts = soup.find_all('li')
for post in posts:
    username = post.find('span', {'class': 'username'})
    content = post.find('div', {'class': 'messagecontent'})

    forum_post = {
        'username': username.text,
        'content': re_break_line.findall(content.text.replace('  ', ''))
    }
    forum_posts.append(forum_post)

print(forum_posts)
```

Output console:

```
[{'content': ['Text before the quote.', "Hello, I'm a quote.", 'Text after the class.'], 'username': 'MostInnovativeUsernameEver'}]
```

Comment: Thx for helping me, even though I had some major problems properly explaining what I'm really trying to do. It didn't work out quite as I thought it would, but you helped me find a solution based on your answer and some further research. :)